# Creating a partial dependant plot for a prediction function

Tags: python, cross-validation, partial-effect, partial-plot

I am working on creating a partial dependant plot for one of my features (B). The problem is that I didn't use any `model` to predict my output (R). I've used a *prediction function* to do that:

```
def objective(B, D, k, fc, Le, N):
    return (k*fc**1.3*B**3.3*D**1.8)/(10**5*N**1.5*Le**0.9)

data=data_set[["B","D","k","fc","Le","N"]]
#data = {'B':[1,2,3],'D':[4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['R'] =  df.apply(lambda x: objective(x.B, x.D, x.k,x.fc,x.Le,x.N), axis=1)

print(df)
```

## What did I try?

I've tried using the `shap` function to create the plot, yet I didn't know what to replace `question_mark.predict` with:

```
import shap
import sklearn
X100 = shap.utils.sample(X, 100) # 100 instances for use as the background distribution

shap.partial_dependence_plot(
    "B", question_mark.predict, X100, ice=False,
    model_expected_value=True, feature_expected_value=True)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: A `.predict()` method and a dataset `X` are sufficient to make partial dependence plots (PDP).

A PDP shows the marginal effect of feature $x_i$ by plotting $x_i$ on the x-axis and the partial dependence function $\widehat{f_i}$ on the y-axis:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{f_i}(x_i) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\hat{f}(x_i,\mathbf{x}_{-i}^{(j)})
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\hat{f}$ generates predictions according to the fitted model, $\mathbf{x}_{-i}$ are the features other than $x_i$ and $\mathbf{x}_{-i}^{(j)}$ are their values for the $j$th observation in the dataset $\mathbf{X}$. So we vary $x_i$ over a grid of values (usually determined by its range in the dataset) but we keep the rest of the features $\mathbf{x}_{-i}$ fixed at their observed values.

To learn more about partial dependence plots, see for example [Interpretation of y-axis in partial dependence plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/463305/237901), [interpreting y axis of a partial dependence plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/121383/237901), [Meaning of y axis in Random Forest partial dependence plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/147763/237901) and the [Interpretable Machine Learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/) book.

---

The question asks for a python implementation. I show how to do it with scikit-learn's [PartialDependenceDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.PartialDependenceDisplay.html) by creating a dummy estimator that applies the predict function to the dataset `X`. The example model is a linear regression with two predictors.

*Note*: According to the documentation, the `PartialDependenceDisplayis.from_estimator` method is new in version 1.0. So make sure you have scikit-learn ≥ 1.0 to run the example below.

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
from sklearn.utils import check_X_y, check_array
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate sample
X, y = make_regression(
    n_samples=100, n_features=2, n_informative=1,
    noise=1, random_state=1234
)
# Fit regressor
reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
reg.fit(X, y)
b0 = reg.coef_[0]
b1 = reg.coef_[1]
```

Make partial dependence plots (PDP) from the regressor object.

```py
display = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(reg, X, [0, 1])
display.plot()
```

[image]

This is for illustration only; we will make exactly the same plots from the regression function $\hat{y} = \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \hat{\beta}_0x_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x_1$.

```py
def objective(x0, x1):
    return b0 * x0 + b1 * x1
```

The idea is to create a `DummyRegressor` class. Its `.fit(X, y)` function doesn't do anything exciting; just accepts the `X` and `y` arguments. Its `.predict(X)` function calls the `objective` function.

```py
class DummyRegressor(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y):
        # Check that X and y have correct shape
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y, y_numeric=True)
        self.X_ = X
        self.y_ = y
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        X = check_array(X)

        # X is an numpy array, not a pandas DataFrame.
        # Make sure the columns of X are in the order required by `objective`
        return objective(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
```

And now we make the partial dependence plots. Since PDPs are the same, I've labeled the x-axis to distinguish them from the previous display.

```py
dummy_reg = DummyRegressor()
dummy_reg.fit(X, y)

display = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(
    dummy_reg, X, [0, 1],
    feature_names=["x0", "x1"]
)
display.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a bit confused on how you defined `X` (You've created a random regression problem). Can you please build on my code? I've updated my code now. How can I define `B` as my `X` using your code? Also I am getting an error: `AttributeError: type object 'PartialDependenceDisplay' has no attribute 'from_estimator'` may you please advise? Thanks again for all this.

Comment: You didn't provide data, so I had to generate some; that's X. And for illustration purposes I decided it's enough that X has two features. I debated whether your questions is off-topic because it's in large part about programming. You should be able to add the entirety of my code. Any other errors as you modify the code are probably better addressed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you want answers to use your code as reference, then you'll have to learn how to provide a minimal reproducible example as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This includes a data sample. No-one but you knows what `"Alpha.xlsx"` is about.

Comment: It seems that you may have an older version of scikit-learn. You won't be able to run this example unless you update to version 1.0. or greater.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I've updated it and no more errors now. Would you please tailor your code to my problem? I'am having difficulties defining the X (in my problem, I have 6 features, and I want to create the PDP for each one). Thanks again for sparing time on this.

Comment: How to modify the code from two features to six features is a purely programming question, so off-topic on Cross Validated. I just wanted to demonstrate that it's enough to have a predict method to make partial dependence plots.

Comment: No problem. Thank you!

Comment: I don't actually see your updated code but the only line you have to change is the return line in the `.predict()` method. You should be careful with the order of the columns in X, because scikit-learn works with numpy arrays not pandas data frames. That's all it should take.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated your code now. But there is a warning that I am getting: `A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().` Is this normal?

Comment: Yep, I said that this is not the place for debugging questions.